# Where is the right place for the adverb 'well' in a sentence?

Tags: adverbs, syntactic-analysis

I want to write: "I understand something."
But I want add emphasis by including the adverb "well".

Which is the right place for it?

1. I well understand something.
2. I understand well something.
3. I understand something well.

I suppose the 3rd option is right, but I still have my doubts.

Comment: Honestly, I think they all work. But 1 & 2 sound better if "something" is replaced with actual content.

Comment: 'I understand the situation well' is acceptable and probably the natural choice. 'I well understand the situation' can be used for added emphasis, but is more formal. 'I well understand the situation that has developed in Elbonia during the last few months of sanctions applied by the Arosian Confederation' _needs_ the 'well' next to the verb; it could be placed immediately after it too. But 'I understand well the situation/him' sounds rarefied to off-planet.

Comment: Thank you for helping me find the right choice for my situation. And also for the correction of the text of my question - it helps a lot to learn on the fly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) "I well understand something" strikes me as somewhat old fashioned, or formal.  (2) "I understand well something" is ungrammatical, due to a prohibition on adverbs coming between verb and direct object.  However, if you have in place of "something" some long and complicated phrase, then this becomes the preferred place for "well".  (3) "I understand something well" is best, but if a complicated phrase is substituted for "something", this becomes worst of the alternatives, rather than best.  *"I understand how to divide by zero well."

John Ross, in his dissertation **Constraints on Variables in Syntax**, [Infinite Syntax](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0893910422), described the difference between (2) and (3) above by formulating a rule "Complex NP Shift" which moves complicated NPs from a position immediately after a verb to the end of a verb phrase.

Comment: +1. Only thing missing (to me, at least) is that the acceptance of (1) in informal, non-archaic use rises along with that of (2); so “I well understand division” is quite formal, but “I well understand how to divide by zero” is less so, and with an object as complex as the one Edwin’s example above, it doesn’t feel formal at all.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, apparently we have a problem parsing constructions that have a complicated phrase in the middle of some upstairs construction.  Moving "well" in either direction, to the beginning of the VP or to the end of the VP solves that problem.  So maybe putting "well" at the beginning of the VP is okay, provided you have a good excuse.

Answer (score 0):

It's the "something that is giving me the problem.  If you understand "it" that well, tell us what it is.  Normally one would say, " I could well understand. . ., but it doesn't work with "something".  One would say: I understood something well, that . . . or I understood one thing well, that. . .

The normal rule, (often broken for effect or 'tone') is to place the adverb as close to th verb as possible and still retain meaning.